# Phonegap Push notification class not found error

Tags: cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

trying to connect with GSM with phonegap cordova 5.4.1 version and i getting error class not found every time how to fix this please

**I want same code for IOS and Android**

my on device load event is this

```
     var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
     pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"824841663931","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"}); 


        // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
          successHandler: function(result) {
           alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
       }
```

and my javascript file is :

```
var PushNotification = function() {
  };


 // Call this to register for push notifications. Content of [options]             
      depends on whether we are working with APNS (iOS) or GCM (Android)
      PushNotification.prototype.register = function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function() {}}

if (typeof errorCallback != "function")  {
    console.log("PushNotification.register failure: failure parameter not a function");
    return
}

if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
    console.log("PushNotification.register failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
    return
}

cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PushPlugin", "register", [options]);
            };

                       // Call this to unregister for push notifications
            PushNotification.prototype.unregister = function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function() {}}

if (typeof errorCallback != "function")  {
    console.log("PushNotification.unregister failure: failure parameter not a function");
    return
}

if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
    console.log("PushNotification.unregister failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
    return
}

 cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PushPlugin", "unregister", [options]);
                               };


                       // Call this if you want to show toast notification on WP8
PushNotification.prototype.showToastNotification = function (successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
    if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function () { } }

    if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
        console.log("PushNotification.register failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return
    }

    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PushPlugin", "showToastNotification", [options]);
}
      // Call this to set the application icon badge
           PushNotification.prototype.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber = function(successCallback, errorCallback, badge) {
if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function() {}}

if (typeof errorCallback != "function")  {
    console.log("PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber failure: failure parameter not a function");
    return
}

if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
    console.log("PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
    return
}

cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PushPlugin", "setApplicationIconBadgeNumber", [{badge: badge}]);
        };

               //-------------------------------------------------------------------

           if(!window.plugins) {
              window.plugins = {};
         }
            if (!window.plugins.pushNotification) {
               window.plugins.pushNotification = new PushNotification();
               }

               if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) {
                module.exports = PushNotification;
               }
```

I am unable to download any plugin . So please help me .

tell me how to register to gcm account
and how to send notification from gcm 
and how to handle on phonegap

**Please share code or solution with me**

Comment: I have resolved error 
I am not making apk of project checking it through phonegap desktop application 
when i created apk for project it runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it as a feature and plugin.
For more details, you may check Phonegap PushPlugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/119

You may also check Push Notification with PhoneGap, How to setup Push Notification: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html

Comment: I have Registered Device on GCM but on post showing InvalidRegistration Please help

Comment: Registration id on the server side should match with the registration id generated on the client side. Check if they are same or not. Check this page to see how you get API key. (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: Please check your permissions in manifest file. You may check the official documentation, here's the link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved error I am not making apk of project checking it through phonegap desktop application when i created apk for project it runs successfully